# ABRecordCopyCompositeName and CFBridgingRelease crash issue

Tags: ios, iphone, sorting, crash, addressbook

I am developing IOS application using AddressBook.

Here is my code what I used.

I am getting crash issue on substringWithRange function.

What is the crash reason?

Thank you.

```
NSString * sort_name = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person));
if (sort_name != nil) {
    [self Make_Sorting_Name:sort_name];


- (NSDictionary *)Make_Sorting_Name:(NSString *)sort_name {

            NSString * sort_char = [[NSString stringWithString:[sort_name substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)]] uppercaseString];

            NSCharacterSet *nonDigits = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
            BOOL containsNonDigitChars = ([sort_char rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonDigits].location == NSNotFound);            

        }
```

Comment: FYI - As of iOS 9.0 you should be using the newer Contacts framework, not the deprecated AddressBook framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ABRecordCopyCompositeName` function might return nil or empty string sometimes. So the case needs to be checked:

```
NSString *sort_char = @""; //or another specific character for sorting
if (sort_name != nil && sort_name.length > 0){
    sort_char = [[NSString stringWithString:[sort_name substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)]] uppercaseString];
}
```

Comment: there is no problem which I used CFBridgingRelease?

Comment: When ABRecordCopyCompositeName will return empty string?

Comment: `CFBridgingRelease` Moves a non-Objective-C pointer to Objective-C and also transfers ownership to ARC. So it's OK.

Comment: ABRecordCopyCompositeName will return empty string when a contact does not have Prefix, Suffix, Organization, First name, and Last name.

Comment: sort_name = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person));
    
    if (sort_name != nil && sort_name.length > 0) {
         [self Make_Sorting_Name:sort_name];
    }
So is it OK above code?

Comment: Looks ok. Please run it to check.

Comment: I added phone number only on contacts, but I can not see which sort_name is empty string. anyway I will check sort_name whether it is empty string or not. Thank you for your help

Comment: Add `else` after if case to check which person's sort_name is empty.